# ggplot barplot: getting each individual token as its own bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I'm trying to make a bar graph like the image below.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER2Fz.png)

For each speaker (1, 2 , and 3) there are 4 tokens (2 for each category, represented by the yellow and grey bars), and I want each individual token to show up like in the picture (2 yellow bars, two grey bars for each speaker); right now, all the tokens are collapsed under their respective category, so that there are only 2 bars for each speaker, one yellow and one grey. How can I get the 4 bars to be represented?

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
ggplot(EUD, aes(x=Speaker, y=EuD, fill=Gliding)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
xlab("Speaker")+
ylab("EuD")+
scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette("Darjeeling1")) +
theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 9, family="Times"))+
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=9, family="Times"))+
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=9, family="Times"))+
theme(legend.title = element_text(size=9, family="Times"),  legend.text = 
element_text(size=9, family="Times"))
```

Thanks!

Lauren

Here was the output of dput(EUD):

```
structure(list(Speaker = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Token = c("HOTEL", "HOST", "NO", 
"TOAST", "SMOKED", "GHOST", "SLOW", "GOING", "COVE", "BOAT", 
"GO", "AGO", "THOSE", "WOKE", "DON\xd5T", "KNOW"), EuD = c(0.071, 
0.271, 1.476, 2.605, 0.403, 0.127, 2.235, 1.348, 0.794, 0.322, 
1.088, 1.543, 0.137, 0.129, 2.462, 1.327), Gliding = c("UNGLIDED", 
"UNGLIDED", "GLIDED", "GLIDED", "UNGLIDED", "UNGLIDED", "GLIDED", 
"GLIDED", "UNGLIDED", "UNGLIDED", "GLIDED", "GLIDED", "UNGLIDED", 
"UNGLIDED", "GLIDED", "GLIDED")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Comment: Hi Lauren, please use `dput(EUD)` on your console, copy the output, edit your question and paste it in order to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
EUD %>%
  group_by(Speaker) %>%
  mutate(Mytoken=paste0(Gliding,row_number())) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Speaker, y=EuD, fill=Mytoken)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",color='black',
           position=position_dodge(),alpha=0.5)+
  xlab("Speaker")+
  ylab("EuD")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('yellow','yellow','gray25','gray25')) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none',
        axis.text = element_text(size = 9, family="Times"))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=9, family="Times"))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=9, family="Times"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size=9, family="Times"),
        legend.text = element_text(size=9, family="Times"))
```

Output:

[image]